# Repeat a sequence of codes

Tags: sequence, repeat

```
<div class="zoom_img">

<a href="1.jpg"><img alt="1.jpg" src="1.jpg"></a>
<a href="2.jpg"><img alt="2.jpg" src="2.jpg"></a>
<a href="3.jpg"><img alt="3.jpg" src="3.jpg"></a>
<a href="4.jpg"><img alt="4.jpg" src="4.jpg"></a>
<a href="5.jpg"><img alt="5.jpg" src="5.jpg"></a>

</div>
```

- I have to add almost 100 pics in this order. So just wondering how to use the for loop to do the job easily :)

Comment: In which language? If none, you could do that in less than a 30 seconds using Excel

Comment: This is in html. Can u pls tell me how to do this in escel. I can copy and paste that sequence in the code then

Comment: HTML has no loops. Use Excel and then copy paste the output back to your HTML page.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to create this in excel.

Comment: You can also do this really easily in Python.  Take a look at my answer below.

Comment: Thank You Jason, Iam checking to do it that way

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about data entry.

Comment: Its a "do it for me" question. Or homework

Comment: Thank you all.I was able to finish it on time. All your help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you need some kind of server language.  For example in php.

```
<?php
      $numOfPhotos = 10; //some value.
      $html = "<div class='zoom_img'>";
      for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfPhotos; $i++) 
      {
          $html = $html . "<a href='" . $i . "jpg'><img alt='" . $i . "jpg'></a>";
      }
          $html = $html . "</div>";

?>
<html>

    <body>
         <!-- Put your normal html -->
         <?php echo $html; ?> <!-- this will insert the html created dynamically -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Someone who doesn't know anything other than HTML is expected to install php for this?

Comment: Someone who doesn't know enough about excel is expected to know what you mean in your comment above?

Comment: I understand where you are coming from but in some situations a person's current knowledge is not good enough and some research in something you haven't done before (php, excel, python) becomes necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a server language, and just want to pregenerate this easily:
Open a terminal, start python (type 'python') and type in:

```
for x in range (0, 100):
    print '<a href=%d.jpg"><img alt="%d.jpg" src="%d.jpg"></a>' %(x, x, x)
```

replacing 100 with whatever number you want to go to.  It will print out the code.

Edit: added front carrot to print

Comment: Someone who doesn't know anything other than HTML is expected to run python?

Comment: Thank You Jason. That worked. http://www.compileonline.com/execute_python_online.php Used this link to execute the script u provided

Comment: No, but I gave clear instructions on how to run it, so someone who knows how to use a computer should be able to follow them, copy and paste, and get it to work.

Comment: Also, this solution modularizes the issue, so if they want to generate a 1000 tags, they can do so easily, without having to ask for someone else to do it, as was the case in your solution.

Comment: Hi Jason, In the code above there seems to be an issue with the front carrot added for Print.

Comment: @user2515101 It's because you're executing it with an online python runner, so the browser is seeing the output as actual HTML code (since the result of this script is a bunch of HTML tags).  It is better to run this outside of a browser.

Answer (score 1):

with JQuery on client side

```
var img;
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    img =  '<a href="' + i +'.jpg"><img alt="' + i + '.jpg" src="' + i + '.jpg"></a>';
    $(".zoom_img" ).add( img);
}
```